# How to create sidemenu with Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So am trying to create a side menu using Jquery. But on Firefox when you try accessing the select option, it disappears. This is the code.

```
 <li class="one_charge">
    <a href="#">
    <i class="fa fa-product-hunt"></i>
        <span>Change Projects</span></a>
        <ul class="sub_one_charge">
            <li>
            <form name="project_selector">
                <select class="selector" name="project_id" id="project_id" onchange="document.forms['project_selector'].submit()">
                      <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
                      <option value="saab">Saab</option>
                      <option value="opel">Opel</option>
                      <option value="audi">Audi</option>
                </select>
                <input type="hidden" name="action" value="redirect" />
            </form>
           </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
```

This is the query

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    (function() {
    "use strict"; 
    jQuery('.custom-nav > li').hover(function() {
            jQuery(this).addClass('side_active nav-hover');  
    },
    function() {
        jQuery(this).removeClass('side_active nav-hover');
    }
    );
}
)(jQuery);
   </script>
```

Comment: Does the same thing happen in any other browser?  Or just Firefox?

Comment: Works well on Chrome and Safari

Comment: Could you post the contents of `side_active nav-hover` class? Also, to shorten your code, you can use `$('.custom-nav > li').hover(function() { $(this).toggle('side_active nav-hover')})`

Comment: Thank you for the comment. The Side_active is just for changing active li. But for nav-hover { display: block; }

Comment: I'm not sure if my question will be stupid or not, but why you set classes with JS ? Just for CSS ?

Comment: it is used for the First letter change. Makes it easy for me

Comment: Why you don't try this CSS selector : .custom-nav > li:hover:first-letter {}, it should works no ?